# Querying types in a co- or contravariant way

Tags: c#, language-design, feature-requests

I posted a c# feature request [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2796518-querying-types-in-a-co-or-contravariant-way); however, I do not get a lot of attention there. Therefore I am asking you here, what you think of it.

---

The `in` and `out` keywords in generic type declarations are useful; however, due to their nature, their application is limited to a small number of types. What I am suggesting here, is to be able to use them in declarations of variables, fields, parameters and possibly properties in order to restrict the set of possible operations on any generic type in a dynamic and temporary way. This would considerably increase the cases where co- and contravariance could be used.

Examples

```cs
// A List of a more derived type can be passed
public void ReadList(IList<out MyType> list)
{
    MyType item = list[0];  // OK
    list[0] = new MyType(); // DISALLOWED because of "out" keyword!
    list.Add(new MyType()); // DISALLOWED because of "out" keyword!
}

// A List of a less derived type can be passed
public void WriteList(List<in MyType> list)
{
    MyType item = list[0];  // DISALLOWED because of "in" keyword!
    list[0] = new MyType(); // OK
    list.Add(new MyType()); // OK
}
```

--

**UPDATE**

Taken these declarations

```
class LessDerived { }

class MyType : LessDerived { }

class MoreDerived : MyType { }
```

You could use the methods shown above like this

```
var listOfLessDerived = new List<LessDerived>();
var listOfMyType = new List<MyType >();
var listOfMoreDerived = new List<MoreDerived>();

ReadList(listOfMyType);
ReadList(listOfMoreDerived);

WriteList(listOfMyType);
WriteList(listOfLessDerived);
```

Comment: Co/contra-variance applies to types, not operations. Your example doesn't involve any subtyping of MyType, so it's not clear how exactly the suggestion applies to covariance as opposed to automatically creating readonly interfaces to types.

Comment: @Telastyn: Generic types can only be used in a covariant way if the generic parameter appears only as output type, e.g. as result type of methods or in property getters. The opposite is true for generic parameter appearing only as input. Therefore types (like `IList<T>` or `List<T>`) where the generic parameter is used as input as well as output type cannot be used in co- or contravariance. If it was either restricted to be used only as input or as output in certain situations, then contra- respectively covariance would apply. By operation I mean either reading (getting) or writing (setting).

Comment: @Telastyn: Please see my update for examples of usage.

Comment: So, you're basically proposing the addition of [Java wildcards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_%28Java%29) to C#?

Comment: Also, the specific case of `ReadList()` is solved in .Net 4.5 by [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And you can follow the same approach in your own code: split invariant interface into covariant, contravariant and invariant parts.

Comment: @svick: I'm not a Java programmer; however, I think that it would correspond to the `extends` and `super` constraints.

Comment: @svick: My first appproach was to split the interface as you say; however, it is not possible to split a property (or an indexer) having a getter as well as a setter and it would require to change existing interfaces. My new approach leaves the existing interfaces untouched, i.e. it is applied where a type (either class, struct or interface) is used.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, it is possible to split a property, but it means you have to use explicit interface implementation in any class that implements the interfaces.

Comment: @svick: Which is quite a restriction, since it means that you don't see the property through the class. Splitting `IList<T>` this way would break existing code. Another option you be to allow C# to "join" a getter and a setter from different interfaces into a new property.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: why is variance required in these examples though? You can simply have a generic method where MyType is the type constraint and it 'just works'.

Comment: I see what you're saying, you would like to enable read-only or write-only operations basically enforcing a command query separation through code. The concern is that once you access a property on a parameter there's no way to guarantee that you didn't make a change to that property. Well there is but I think it would take more effort than the benefit.

Comment: I do like where you're going though so you get my upvote.

Comment: @Telastyn: How do you want to add an item of type `MyType` to a `List<T>`? The list could be a `List<MyType>` or a `List<LessDerived>` but not a `List<MoreDerived>` and there is no constraint that allows to say `where T is MyType or less derived`.

Comment: `public static void Add<T, U>(List<T> list, U obj) where U : T { list.Add(obj); }`

Comment: @MikeBrown: Yes, the read/write query separation enables co- and contravariance on a type that is not read-only or write-only otherwise. The same collection could be treated as read-only at one place and as write-only at antoher place, what is not possible with a ReadOnlyList for instance.

Comment: @Telastyn: I used a similar pattern somewhere; however, what do you make, if the second parameter (`U obj`) is not there or if you know in advance that `U` has the concrete type `MyType`? I am just trying to extend what is already possible to do today in C# with the `in` and `out` keywords to more situations.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: if you don't have the second parameter, then Add is meaningless. It is good to look to improve things, but you haven't been able to produce a meaningful scenario where the suggestion gains you anything. Honestly, I suspect that the core idea is not type-safe, but can't tell since I cannot gather your intentions.

Comment: @Telastyn: It is absolutely type-safe like the original implementation of [variance in C# 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff628440#variance). You can create the object to be added inside the method and don't need a parameter for this. Variance in C# 4.0 works only for types where a generic parameter appears either only as input or only as output. My idea allows variance for types where this generic apperas in inputs as well as outputs in certain situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The in and out keywords in generic type declarations are useful; however, due to their nature, their application is limited to a small number of types. What I am suggesting here, is to be able to use them in declarations of variables, fields, parameters and possibly properties in order to restrict the set of possible operations on any generic type in a dynamic and temporary way.

Java has this feature. An interesting fact: the "call site" variance feature in Java and the "declaration site" variance feature in C# were both designed in large part by my colleague Mads Torgersen.

> I am asking you here, what you think of it.

It's a reasonable feature with many interesting scenarios. We considered it and rejected it. The benefits did not outweigh the costs.

Comment: I had hoped secretly that Eric would bump into my question. I fully understand your decision. Not only the implementation costs have to be considered but also the costs of learning and mastering new language features. I started with C# 1.0 and had the opportunity to learn new features one by one; however, people new to C# are confronted with a large number of features from the beginning.

Comment: It's interesting to note that Scala has chosen to go the [C# way](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/129) (declaration-site variance), presumably because call-site variance is harder for clients of your classes.